# Why does = change to $\leq$ and then to = in this proof of |a+b| = |a|+|b|?

Tags: calculus, self-learning

From Spivak's Calculus.

> This proof is motivated by the observation that |a| = $\sqrt {a^2}$. $\sqrt x$ denotes the *positive* square root of x; this symbol is defined only when x $\geq 0$. We may now observe that.

$$
(|a + b|)^2 = (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 
\leq a^2 + 2|a| |b| + b^2 \\
=|a|^2 + 2|a| |b| + |b|^2 
=(|a| + |b|)^2 
$$

I don't understand why the $\leq$ appears in line 2, and then changes to $=$ in line 3. Thank you.

Comment: As written, this proof not correct (take $a = b = 1$). Are you sure you have copied it correctly from Spivak?

Comment: I think you "proof" is not valid. Take - for instance - $a=1, b= -1$. Then $\vert a + b \vert = 0$ while $\vert a \vert + \vert b \vert = 2$. 

Furthermore, if you want to put an inequality between the first and the second line, there's a $2$ missing.

Comment: you mean that you don't see why $2ab \le 2|a||b|?$  take $a = 1, b = -1.$

Comment: I seem to recall having an instructor once who preferred to write $\leq$ instead of $=$ in such cases even when $=$ is true, because it is always possible to do so (since $x=y$ implies $x\leq y$) and because it does not weaken the final result.

Comment: Sorry, the second line should say 2|a|*|b|, but the rest is correct.

Comment: After reading all the comments and answers, I understand better. I was having trouble seeing $ab \leq |a||b|$. Another way of looking at this that helped me, is to picture the chain all on one line. With the visually stacked presentation I kept comparing lines 2-4 to $(|a|+|b|)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

In the second line, we have $ab \leq |a||b|$. This is true because if $ab\leq0$ then $ab\leq 0 \leq |a|b|$. If $ab\geq 0 $ then $ab=|ab|=|a||b|$. In any case it holds.

In the third line we use that $a^2=|a^2|$ and $b^2=|b^2|$ which is true because $a^2,b^2 \geq 0$. Notice we used that on the very first step as well, but the other way around.

Now, the inequality doesn't vanish. The end result is $(|a+b|)^2 \leq (|a|+|b|)^2$.

What we have done is essentially this: $A \leq B = C \Rightarrow A \leq C$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really "change" in the sense that the equality is replaced by an inequality or vice versa; what you have here is a chain of equations and an inequality, which say that $(|a+b|)^2 = (a+b)^2$ **and** $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$  **and** $a^2+2ab+b^2\leq a^2+2|a|*|b|+b^2$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the line 2 you have dropped a "2" since it is $|a|^2+2|a||b|+|b|^2$. Also, in the line 2, $\le$ appears because $ab\le |ab|$. For the line 3 it is "=" since $a^2=|a|^2$ and $b^2=|b|^2$.